# How to set Google Translate to show a word's phonogram?

Tags: google-translate

I know it has phonetic but sometimes it isn't convenient for listening.

My native language is Chinese. I just want to know how the English word will be pronounced. Does anyone know how to setup or configure Google Translate to show that information?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I have the same problem.

1. In the **Target Language** side, mouse over the bottom of the text box. 
   You may see icons you did not see before.  There are 5 icons. 
   The third and middle icon looks like an A with two dots on top.
2. Click the third and middle **icon** (that looks like an A with two dots on top).

Now you see the phonetic version of the translation below the target language box.

[image: ![Click on the icon-button circled in red]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfaKa.png)

Look the symbol with the red around it on the right side. That is the icon button you need to click on if the phonetic translation is not being displayed automatically.

Comment: Sometime it doesn't show that icon: https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_c#zh-CN/en/%E7%BF%BB%E8%AD%AF

Comment: Sometimes the possibility does not exist. For instance, it doesn't work for Hebrew.  That is very annoying to me because I live in Israel. I hope Google will work on this.

Comment: I am curious what language are you trying to see the phonetics for?

Comment: I just want English only, not any other non-popular language.

Answer (score -2):

you can change to another chrome extension.
Google translate extension cannot do this